# java: You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-lombok-plugin

After upgrade, Unable to run the application from intellij IDE.

Intellij version : IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-203.5981.155, built on December 1, 2020

lombok version : 0.32-EAP

Error :

```
java: You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled.
  Your processor is: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24
  Lombok supports: sun/apple javac 1.6, ECJ
```

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2592? Does updating to the latest Lombok version help?

Comment: for me lombok plugin version is. 0.32-EAP. no updates after that?

Comment: You are mixing up Lombok IntelliJ IDEA plug-in and Lombok dependency used in your project. These two are completely unrelated. You need to update the latter.

Comment: Related bug report for IDEA: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252069

Comment: Same issue with version 2021.1, Build #IU-211.6693.111. Hopefully, solved with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 373, accepted):

Using lombok 1.18.16 did not work for me. I added the argument below in the build process VM options in

```
-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false
```

Setting:-

> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Shared build process VM
> options

and it worked
https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2592

Comment: This solution fitted better for me because my lombok version is defined from a parent spring dependency. Thanks man.

Comment: Worked also for me without changing dependencies... Thank you!

Comment: Go to IntelliJ | Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment |

Comment: Note that the Lombok Plugin comes with a setting to automatically add the VM option for Lombok versions <1.18.16. However the problem also occurs with higher versions. For those you still have to set the option as described in this answer.

Answer (score 84):

For the impatient one (like myself) add

```
-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false
```

to 'Shared build process VM options:'

[image]

Comment: this worked for me after doing `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 81):

This issue is introduced in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 (Community Edition) Build #IC-203.5981.155.

You can fix it by adding this dependency into your project -

**Maven -**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle -**

```
providedCompile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.16'
```

Comment: added this in pom file in a spring boot project, says 1.18.16 is not found

Comment: unchecked the Lombok IntelliJ plugin then did maven menu->reload project from within IntelliJ after adding 1.18.16 version in pom file, then it worked

Comment: This didn't fix the issue at once on our multi-module project.
I installed the root pom first (which declares lombok.version property) so that IntelliJ would use the right lombok dependency to build, disabled IntelliJ Lombok plugin, restarted and ran mvn idea:idea to get a successful build
Not sure what actually fixed the workspace, I'll update this comment as other teammates will run through this.

Comment: Worked after "Reload All Maven Projects", no disabling Lombok plugin or restarting IntelliJ needed.

Comment: Thanks! @Amit
Spent a lot of time changing the intelliJ settings like Annotation Processor, Plugin Registry.

Comment: It's not ideal to have to change your project because of an upgrade in your IDEA. In a lot of cases, you can't even do that. I think the other solution with `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false` is better, until you are able to upgrade your dependencies to that lombok version.

Comment: update lombok version, mvn idea:idea and mvn clean:install did it. thx @AlexisLEGROS

Comment: Arf, can't update my comment anymore!
As @ugurkocak1980 mentionned, lombok version update + `mvn idea:idea clean install` seem to get your build back on track

Comment: This did not work for me. Also, even if it did it would not be acceptable to tell the entire team that they have to do this in order to get the projects operational. This is a barrier to roll out Lombok to the team.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue here after updating my Intellij Community to 20.3.
The issue could be solved by updating the lombok plugin to 1.18.16

Comment: i dint get any update from Intellij n lombok after the above metioned version.

Comment: @Thanga You are mixing up Lombok IntelliJ IDEA plug-in and Lombok dependency used in your project. These two are completely unrelated. You need to update the latter.

Comment: @CrazyCoder oh ok..I thought this issue is occurring because of intellij-lombok-plugin. Can we update lombok in project just for IDE issue?

Comment: This one fixed it for me - no custom VM options required. Went from `1.18.6` to `1.18.24`

Answer (score 12):

Perform this steps to resolve this issue -->

1. Click on IntelliJ Idea near File Menu from header
2. Open Preferences
3. Click on Build, Execution, Deployment
4. Go to Compile
5. Inside the User-local build process VM options -> Add this command
   -Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false
6. Apply the changes

Comment: What does the command do exactly?

Answer (score 6):

Intellij CE Version: 2020.3 Lombok issue fixed by simply updating POM dependency. Example,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Also remember tp update Lombok version in <annotationProcessorPaths> in pom.xml:

Answer (score 5):

**With this version:**

- Version: **2020.3**
- Build: 203.5981.155
- 1 December 2020

**I've got this message:**

> ⚠ You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled

---

**So,**

**I added lombok plugin in IntelliJ:**

[image: install lombok plugin]

**I enabled it:**
[image]

**I downloaded the last lombok Jar:** https://projectlombok.org/downloads/lombok.jar

**And installed it manually:**
[image: download lombok jar]

**Add it in Platform settings**
[image: add lombok jar in platform settings]

And, **now, it works** fine!

---

***PS**: The version of my **project** Lombok **dependency** is **1.18.8** while the one of the downloaded **plugin** installed **jar** in platform settings is **1.18.16***.

Answer (score 4):

- Go to IntelliJ | Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment |
- Compiler Find Build process VM options or Shared build process VM
- options Add string -Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false into the text
- box Hit save

Answer (score 3):

Another cause could be that you updated the lombok version and forgot to update the version of the lombok plugin:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.20</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- needs to match -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.20.0</version>
<!-- [...] plugin config -->
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

java: You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled.
Your processor is: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27
Lombok supports: sun/apple javac 1.6, ECJ

Upgrade your lombok version by adding below dependencies for gradle, as this is the version supported by updated Intellij 2020.3:

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a dependency module running in the project that used another version of lombok. Another spring-boot version to be more precise. With it's BOM comes another lombok version.

[image: version warning]

Answer (score 1):

My project has lombok in version 1.18.16 yet intellij 2020.3 refused to compile my code and above answers did not help:(.

Eventually tweeking in settings->"build,execution,deployment"->compiler->"annotation processors" worked :). Make sure to enable "annotation processing" and "obtain processors from classpath" checkboxes .

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVrac.png)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using the maven-compiler-plugin configuration and specify the annotationProcessorPaths as follows:

Note I also have mapstruct, so hence the extra paths.

inside build/plugins:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
              <version>${mapstruct-processor.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

My dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

My properties:

```
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <mapstruct-processor.version>0.2.0</mapstruct-processor.version>
    <!-- Bumped version of lombok temporarily to avoid issues with IntelliJ 2020.3+ until we have upgraded to a more recent version of spring boot. -->
    <lombok.version>1.18.20</lombok.version>
```

Note:
I override the lombok version to 1.18.20 since I'm still on an older version of spring boot which uses 1.18.12 under the hood...

Comment: Using Intellij version 2021.1.3 Ultimate the solution "-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false" did not work nor did merely adding a explicit lombok dependency in the pom file. However adding the <annotationProcessorPaths> element to the maven compiler plugin along with adding a lombok dependency did work.

Comment: Yeah I didn't use `Djps.track.ap.dependencies` either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I solved updating IntelliJ to 2021.1.1 version:
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-211.7142.45, built on April 30, 2021

Answer (score 1):

add scope as provided `<scope>provided</scope>.`

This will not give any issues on compile time

Answer (score 0):

For me, I disabled the bundled Lombok plugin. Then enabled it again and reloaded the maven project. Boomshakalaka.

Lombok 1.18.22

IDEA 2021.3 #IU-213.5744.223

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I couldn't make it work no matter what options I tried in the settings. I finally managed to make it work by following the bare instructions  on [lombok with ecj page](https://projectlombok.org/setup/ecj). I downloaded lombok.jar and added this in the `Shared build process VM options` :

```
-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false -javaagent:/path/to/lombok/jar/lombok.jar=ECJ
```

This was using this system :

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)

Build #IU-221.6008.13, built on July 19, 2022

Macbook pro with a M1 pro

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was running code with **mapstruct** and forgot to compile.
When IntelliJ builds and tries to run, that error shows.

After running **mvn clean install -U** through **Windows prompt** and clicking button **Reload All Maven Projects**, the project runs correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with jetbrains 2023.2. I had a lombok version 1.18.22. First i needed to deprecate to 1.18.20 and build it. After that I rebuild it with 1.18.22 and works like a charm. Maybe intellj can not autodetect the version diff with lombok plugin...It's just a hint, but this was the only way I can fix it...

Answer (score -3):

You need to enable the *bundled* plugin.

Since version 2020.3 the Lombok plugin is build-in, you don't need to download a separate plugin (which won't work anymore). Find it in *installed* plugins (not in *marketplace*) and simply enable it.

[image: it's bundled1]

That plugin doesn't have *homepage* link anymore and has a different description.

[image: new plugin description]

Comment: i couldnt find lombok plugin-bundled in installed . can you please help me here